# $T(M \oplus N) = T(M) \otimes T(N) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(N)...$

Tags: commutative-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $M,N$ are $R$-modules, $T(M),T(N)$ their tensor algebras over $R$. In page $571$, D. Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*, the author states the following:

> $T(M \oplus N) = T(M) \otimes T(N) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(N) \otimes...$, *the set of finite sums of tensor products of elements all but finitely many of which are* $1 \in R = T_0(M) = T_0(N)$.

I have tried and could not explicit the equality, I believe that it should be just deduced from the commutativity of tensor product and direct sum. Moreover, in case of graded modules, $M = \oplus M_i$, we can grade the tensor algebra by:
$$T(M)_i = \oplus_{j_1+...+j_n = i}M_{j_1} \otimes... \otimes M_{j_n},$$
and the symmetric algebra $S(M)$ is the quotient algebra defined by the relations:
$$ab = (-1)^{\left|a \right|\left|b \right|}ba, \ a^2 = 0 \ \text{if} \ \left|a \right| \ \text{odd}.$$
Then from the equality $T(M \oplus N) = T(M) \otimes T(N) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(N) \otimes...$, the author again deduce that $S(M \oplus N) = S(M) \otimes S(N)$. I am not really satisfied with his argument so perhaps it is better if someone could help me write down the isomorphism.

Comment: I think the equation is not really well written in the statement. Maybe you can show using distributibity of the tensor product with respect to direct sum that the $n$-fold tensor product $\otimes^n(M\oplus N)$ is the direct sum of all possible $n$-fold tensor products of $M$ and $N$ (there are in total $2^n$ summands).

Comment: @Javi, right, I did try that idea, but I was stuck because I did not know where the numbers 1 come from. For instance, I am so confused when he write the image of an element $m \in M$ via the diagonal map $\Delta: S(M) \to S(M) \otimes S(M)$ is $m \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes m$.

Comment: I don't know what role the diagonal map plays here because I'm not looking at the book, just as the question. But I believe the confusion about the first statement comes from the way the author writes it. If you write it as I did in the comment all tensor strings are finite because each of them is an $n$-fold tensor product, but the autor writes an infinite tensor product, so the only way to get finiteness is by imposing that all but finitely many elements are 1. (similar to infinite direct sum having almost all components equals 0, I hope this helps)

Comment: So I would say it is easier to deduce $S(M\oplus N)=S(M)\otimes S(N)$ from my comment.  In the symmetric algebra you can use the commutativity relation on each $n$-tensor string to move all elements of $M$ to the left and all elements of $N$ to the right. You would still have to fill in the details but [here's a reference](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/grad.hndts/OX+ext+sym.pdf) (page 9)

Comment: @Javi, right, using the skew relation I can see that $n$-tensor string involve both elements of $M$ and $N$ but in case, for instance, what is the image of a homogeneous element $m \in M$ in $S(M)\otimes S(N)$?

Comment: Are you identifying $m\in M$ with $(m,0)$ in $M\oplus N$ as a direct summand of $S(M\oplus N)$?

Comment: Sure, I just realized that here the author implicitly used the isomorphism $M \cong M \otimes R$ so $m$ goes to $m \otimes 1$. In particular, the image of $m$ via the diagonal map is $m \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes m$. That was what I was confused at first place.